# jquery auto hide after click when using toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I use this simple jquery :

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("#langs_current").click(function(){    
        $("#langz").toggle(350);  
     });
   });
```

Currently the new `div#langz` is showing/hidding as I need it, but this happens only when I click on the link `#langs_current`.

I need it to autohide if user click out of those links. What is the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a click event to the body of the page that would check a flag to see if you are currently showing or hiding the `div#langz`.

```
var hideLangz = false;

$(document).ready(function(e) {  
  $("#langs_current").click(function(){     
    $("#langz").toggle(350);   
    hideLangz = true;
  });

  $("body").click(function(){     
    if (hideLangz) {
      $("#langz").toggle(350);   
      hideLangz = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can also check the visibility/current style instead of using a boolean flag. Variable reduction imho improves maintainability.

Comment: The `hideLangz` variable doesn't seem to have a reason for being in the global scope, why not declare it in the `document.ready` event handler? By putting this variable in the global scope you are creating  overhead each time the variable is looked-up.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits the use-case, but you can listen on the `document` and check the `currentTarget`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var tg = $("#langz");
        if (e.currentTarget.id == "langs_current") {
             tg.toggle(350);
        } else {
             tg.hide(350);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are taking a DOM element, creating a jQuery object from it, then using the jQuery `.attr()` function to get the ID (which is available before you created the jQuery object): `if (e.currentTarget.id == "langs_current") {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a `click` event handler to the `document` element to grab all clicks on a page. Then in an event handler for the `#langs_current` element you can stop the propagation of the `click` event so it doesn't reach the `document` element (and it's event handler):

```
$(function() { 
    $("#langs_current").click(function(event){

        //stop the propagation of this event so it doesn't reach the `document` element which would hide the `#langz` element
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("#langz").toggle(350);
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        //the user has clicked on something other than `#langs_current`, run the needed code now

        //hide the `#langz` element if the `document` element receives a `click` event 
        //(which it won't if the user clicks on the `#langs_current` element since it stops the propagation of the event
        $("#langz").hide();
    });
});
```

- Docs for `event.stopPropagation()`: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Here is a demo of using `event.stopPropagation()` to register clicks off of an element: http://jsfiddle.net/aX2VE/1/

Answer (score 0):

My Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zHNtp/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $("#langs_current").click(function(){    
        $("#langz").toggle(350);
        return false;
     });

    $('body').click(function(){
        $('#langz').hide(350);
        return false;
    });
});
```

should do this.

Comment: The reason this works is because `return false;` inside a jQuery event handler is the same thing as: `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropatation()` (`.stopPropagation()` being the important one in this case).

Answer (score -2):

Use the jQuery .mouseout() function.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

This should get the job done.

Comment: The question is regarding how to hide the element when a `click` event occurs outside another element.